# Issue with VBA code to create Pivot from column of data

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a column of data. I have a userform with a Commandbutton on it, which is supposed to create a pivot table from the column of data.

The desire result is to create a pivot table, which counts the number of times each number appears in the column of data. However, my code only shows a count of all of the numbers (i.e. the number of rows of data).

Can someone please assist me and tell me where I am going wrong?

The output required is two columns, the first being the row labels listing each number and the second being a count of these numbers, showing how many times each one appears.

````
     Dim PSheet As Worksheet
     Dim DSheet As Worksheet
     Dim LastRow As Long
     Dim LastCol As Long
     Dim PRange As Range
     Dim PCache As PivotCache
     Dim PTable As PivotTable

     Sheets.Add
     ActiveSheet.Name = "Pivottable"

    Set PSheet = Worksheets("Pivottable")
    Set DSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = DSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

    Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="PRIMEPivotTable")


   With PTable.PivotFields("Calling Number")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1

End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PRIMEPivotTable").PivotFields("Calling Number")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1

    End With


    PTable.AddDataField PSheet.PivotTables _
        ("PRIMEPivotTable").PivotFields("Calling Number"), "Count of Calling Number", xlCount


End Sub```
````

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you've run afoul of some VBA pickiness, and also a little redundancy.

I edited your code to read as follows:

```
Sub foo()

    Dim PSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DSheet As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim PRange As Range
    Dim PCache As PivotCache
    Dim PTable As PivotTable

    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Pivottable"

    Set PSheet = Worksheets("Pivottable")
    Set DSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set PRange = DSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

    Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="PRIMEPivotTable")

    PTable.AddDataField PSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PRIMEPivotTable").PivotFields("Calling Number"), "Count of Calling Number", xlCount

    With PTable.PivotFields("Calling Number")
         .Orientation = xlRowField
         .Position = 1
    End With


End Sub
```

You've got three operations on the pivot table in your code.  (1) you add 'Calling Number' to the column headers.  (2) you add 'Calling Number' to the row headers.  (3) you add a count of Calling Numbers to data fields.

You don't need (1).  We're just doing the row headers.  Also, and for some reason, when you are using the same field in DataFields as in PivotFields, you have to add the pivot fields AFTER you add the data fields.  I don't really know why, I admit I stumbled on it by accident.  But running the above code snip over some test data I get the following (which I think is what you're after)

[image]
[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Ryan. Thank you ever so much for your assistance. I have just ran the code with your amendments, but I have encountered an error on my line: `PTable.AddDataField PSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PRIMEPivotTable").PivotFields("Calling Number"), "Count of Calling Number", xlCount`  It says Method PivotTables of object_Worksheet failed

Comment: I believe that this error means Excel is having a hard time finding the pivot table - maybe because we're pointing to the wrong sheet or the pivot hasn't actually been created thanks to some other problem.  Try stepping through the code and confirming that Pivottable worksheet is active when this code executes, that your pivot table is actually there (should show up as that blanks space-holder with no fields) and that all of the sheets/tables are named as expected.

Comment: Hi Ryan, just for clarity can you confirm what my full code should look like? Just to be sure that I have changed the right parts etc.

Comment: Chris, I'm sorry that this isn't working so smoothly :(  I edited my post to include the whole subroutine that I tested with.  I'm running 32bit Excel 2016 on Windows 10.

Comment: Hi Ryan. I believe I may have located the error. As I provided a test workbook when asking my question, the test data started from Column A in Sheet 1. However, the actual data I am working on starts from L2 (with the Column Header being in L2) on Sheet 4.